# What is the difference while exporting the env variable in linux from a file?

Tags: linux, export, environment-variables

I'm  working on Linux.
What is the difference between following export statements of two environmental variables?

```
export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export MANPATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the syntax `${PATH:+:$PATH}` (used for expanding `$PATH`) takes care of the (pathological) case that `$PATH` is empty (or unset).  In this case, the result will be empty, otherwise it will be `:$PATH`, ensuring that the result of the expansion will be either `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin` alone (in the pathological case) or `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin:$PATH` in the typical case.

The expansion of `$MANPATH` does not take care of the pathological case, so in case `$MANPATH` was empty or unset, the result will be `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man:`, containing a stray colon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In linux/unix `PATH` is standard environment variable for searching required executable and other files from any point. So your shell searches through when you enter a command. Using first command.To modify path it depend on shells like Bash, Sh, Ksh shell.

```
 export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

It append your given path to standard Linux env path.

While in second one

```
export MANPATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man:$MANPATH
```

you create your custom path name (MANPATH) and exported it so you can now access whole path using $MANPATH variable.

Note that above path modification is temporary . for permanent changes you need to modify ~/.profile file for sh and ksh shell, or ~/.bash_profile file for bash shell.

For example in BASH shall

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin'  >> ~/.bash_profile
```